# How to display route direction form current location to destination point in IOS7

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes

Hi in my application i have the map navigation i have the destination point now want to navigate form my current position to destination its not working.

My navigation code.

```
- (IBAction)direction:(id)sender {
  NSString *urlString =@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=12.9259,77.6229";
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}
```

i have used the above code when i click the button its showing like.

```
directions not available A route cannot be determined form this start location.
```

Like this I'm getting in map please tell me how to  resolve this issue where I'm doing wrong in above code.

Thanks.